# Show for any matrix $A$ with positive determinant, there is a continuous path in $GL_+(n,R)$ from $A$ to the identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, path-connected

Can someone please help me prove the following?

Prove $GL_+(n,R)$ is path connected. That is, show that for any matrix $A$ with positive determinant, there is a continuous path in $GL_+(n,R)$ from $A$ to the identity.

$\textbf{My idea:}$ Start with diagonal matrices, then upper/lower-triangular matrices, then arbitrary matrices.

Comment: $t \mapsto \exp((1-t) \log A)$. (The $\log A$ is not necessarily unique.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depending on which [matrix decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) you like the best. Using [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) it suffices to prove the result for matrices in $SO(n)$ and for upper triangular matrices with positive diagonal.

- For upper triangular matrices $U$ with positive diagonal it is very easy and a linear interpolation $(1 - t) U + t I$ works (every intermediate step is another upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal; the space of such matrices is convex).
- For matrices in $SO(n)$ you can use the spectral theorem to show that the exponential map $\exp : \mathfrak{so}(n) \to SO(n)$ is surjective, then linearly interpolate in $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ (every element of $SO(n)$ is a direct sum of rotations and you are interpolating the degrees of the rotations), or you can use [Givens rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

Similarly, using [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) it suffices to prove the result for matrices in $SO(n)$ and for diagonal matrices with positive diagonal (also convex), and using [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) it suffices to prove the result for matrices in $SO(n)$ and for positive-definite symmetric matrices (also convex).

The appearance of $SO(n)$ in all of these results can be explained abstractly as follows: every connected Lie group $G$ has a [maximal compact subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) $K$, and as a manifold is diffeomorphic to $K \times \mathbb{R}^n$. (So $G$ deformation retracts onto $K$, meaning the two are homotopy equivalent and share e.g. the same homotopy groups and (co)homology, and in particular the same $\pi_0$.) And the maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ is $SO(n)$.

Comment: There is also an inductive argument that $SO(n)$ is connected coming from looking at the fiber bundle $SO(n-1) \to SO(n) \to S^{n-1}$ coming from its action on the sphere. It's overkill for proving connectivity but the standard tool for computing other homotopy groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Gauss decomposition
$$g = l\cdot u$$
where $l$ is lower triangular, and $u$ is upper triangular. It works for $g$ in a dense open subset defined by "all principal minors non-zero".

So: take $g'$ with positive determinant.  Get $g$ close by, with positive determinant and all principal minors non-zero. Now join $g'$ to $g$ by a segment ( $g$ was chosen close enough to $g'$), and reduce the problem to connecting $g$.  Connect $l$ and $u$ to diagonal matrices. Now reduce to a diagonal matrix ( with elements $\pm 1$).  Pair the $-1$ if any, look at them as rotations by $\pi$. You are mostly done.